# distinguish requests from the same vehicle

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am implementing an small app to track buses based on Crowdsorcing. The riders send data `long, lat, mac, route` to the server as JSON string.

In my database I have table `bus` to insert the transmitted data. One record in the `bus` table represents one bus vehicle. Therefore, one rider should  update the record of the bus vehicle in the case of many riders are sitting in the same bus and their devices transmit data to the server from the same bus.

To reach that I have tried to filter the requests from the same bus with the aid of the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) but it is overkill for short distance. Is there another way to reach that without taking into consideration the distance between the sender of the requests?

Comment: Doesn't `Route` give you a bus number and thus identify the bus? Also, what's wrong with multiple reports about the same bus? After all, you are tracking its movement. I don't think that I quite understand the problem; could you please clarify? Thanks.  Are you perhaps checking for invalid bus number?

Comment: or isn't the `mac` the ID of the transmitter?

Comment: I think the issue is how to correctly aggregate incoming reports into the correct instance of a bus. In other words, it is a kind of signal processing, and may involve spatial queries, averaging, and rejection of obviously inaccurate data. For example, the JSON datum mentioned in the question is missing the "direction of travel", and this will cause two buses traveling on the same route in opposite directions to be confused by the system.

Comment: @Mawg: yes routes gives me the route  but there is many buses serve the same route(route 5 is being served by 20 buses).

Comment: Disambiguation of buses traveling in opposite directions are usually done with e.g. "north-south", "east-west", "inbound-outbound" (with respect to a bus depot or public transportation hub).

Comment: The JSON datum is also missing a "timestamp", because there can be a significant delay between the time of GPS measurement and the time the application's message finally reaches the web server.

Comment: @ratchet freak: yes the mac is the uniques key of the record but I dont want to create one record of every transmitter bus table  since I want to display these records in google map

Comment: @rwong: I have the timestamp in the json string but I have not mentioned it. The direction I will add it later.

Comment: @Mawg: but how can I display the bus when the bus is reprenseted by many trasmitters in the bus table I have to filter these rerords before displaying them at the map? Please clarify me you point thnaks

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the problem you want to associate the position/time data from the device with a bus.

presumably you have the timetable information server side, so you know how many buses there are and roughly what times they are at the various stops.

you have multiple position/time/device messages with a degree of error in the position/time measurement which may come from:

- A: 2 devices in a single bus - appears that there are 2 buses at the same location
- B: 2 buses at the same location, 1 device per bus - appears that there is 1 bus

You can only resolve these scenarios with additional data. ie. if you have two devices which approach and then separate, you can infer that there are two buses. If the two devices closely match position (i would just use euclidean maths) over a period of time consistent with a bus timetable you can infer that they are on the same bus.

Due to the large errors in gps location, in cities particularly, the chances are you are going to get a lot of inconsistent data. If you try and display this in real time the visualization will flicker as you reinterpret the data over time.

You can get around this by trusting the timetables more than the data. I would try and detect events from the aggregate data

- Bus stopped between stops for more than x amount of time
- Bus in slow traffic. significantly lagging time table

unless this type of thing occurs just show the bus position based on the timetable

Comment: I want to associate many requests from the same bus with one  record in the `bus` table, to filter them before the visualization  in google map. My main problem is with 2 or many devices in the same bus. You said I can use `euclidean maths` to solve such as cases. Please can you explain how can I use `euclidean maths` to solve this poblem?

Comment: rather than using the haversine formula you can just use x^2+y^2 < threashold value.

Comment: do the x and y represent the long and lat of the same record in the table?

Comment: @Ewan: Plugging `(lat, lon)` directly into the 2D Pythagoras formula will not give the correct - not even an approximately useful - result at all. See [this question on math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/637108/10668) for a correctly worked example.

Comment: @Ewan: [This article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Expressing_latitude_and_longitude_as_linear_units) explains why this is the case. As latitude changes, the linear distance that correspond to a small change in longitude and latitude (in other words, their ratios) change as well, and the ratios become different. Thus, one unit of `lat` and one unit of `lon` will not correspond to the same linear distance anymore, unless you follow the steps described in the article(s) linked above.

Comment: it seems insignificant when you are talking about the size of a bus. you could simplify even further and just look at the diff in lat/long

Answer (score 1):

There's really no reason to convert away from degrees.  Just do a simple comparison:

```
if abs(lat1 - lat2) < lat_threshold and abs(long1 - long2) < long_threshold:
```

The trick is in setting appropriate thresholds.  This will vary depending on your location, but for your purpose could be considered constant across a metropolitan area, so you can calculate them once manually, or set them empirically.  It also gives you a rectangle instead of a circle, but that's also negligible for your purposes.

Keep in mind if you don't want to deal with estimating velocity and such, you'll need some way of ensuring reports are synchronized in time.